# What would be a Rust idiomatic way to have a vector of traits with aliases for individual vector items?

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker, unsafe

I'm currently working on a small status bar for Sway WM. The bar is composed of multiple objects implementing a `Widget` trait.
Amongst all widgets, the clock is a little special. I don't just want to render it, but I also want to ensure its rendering is done in a timely fashion, otherwise the time displayed often ends up being a little off. Due to this requirement, I need to both work with the clock as a `Widget` and also as its own `Clock`.

The issue I'm facing is that once the clock widget is stored in a vector with the other widgets, the borrow checker does not allow any mutable references outside of the vector to exist. This made it impossible to use the clock as an instance of `Clock` within the main application loop.

The cleanest way I found to solve the issue, without introducing runtime overhead, was through raw pointers and unsafe code. I'd like to know of other zero runtime overhead solutions to this problem.

Here's an over-simplified version of the code that illustrates what the current code looks like:

```rust
trait Widget {
    fn update_info(&mut self);
    fn render(&self);
}

struct NetworkStatus{}
impl Widget for NetworkStatus {
    fn update_info(&mut self) {
        // query the OS for network information
    }
    fn render(&self) {
        println!("Connected wirelessly");
    }
}

struct Clock{}
impl Widget for Clock {
    fn update_info(&mut self) {
        // query the OS for the current time
    }
    fn render(&self) {
        println!("2024-03-06T19:25:17");
    }
}
impl Clock {
    fn get_alignment_delay(&mut self) -> std::time::Duration {
        return std::time::Duration::new(1, 0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut netstat = NetworkStatus{};
    let mut clock = Clock{};
    let clock_ptr = &mut clock as *mut Clock;

    let mut widgets: Vec<&mut dyn Widget> = vec![
        &mut netstat,
        &mut clock,
    ];

    loop {
        for w in widgets.iter_mut() {
            w.update_info();
        }

        for w in widgets.iter() {
            w.render();
        }

        std::thread::sleep(unsafe {
            (*clock_ptr).get_alignment_delay()
        });
    }
}
```

I'm aware that different architectures could solve the issue, but I'm just interested in learning some solutions for this exact problem so that I'll know what to do the next time I see something similar.

Comment: I know this is simplified and all, but why do the widgets need to be mutable refs in the first place? Their `render` methods don't need mutable references. Why is `get_alignment_delay` receiving a mutable reference? Seems like even a non-toy example it would only need read access. If neither of these can be changed, I'd assume you'd need to make use of [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/interior-mutability.html) via the [interior mutability pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), but I'm too new to Rust to explain it adequately myself.

Comment: _"The cleanest way I found to solve the issue, without introducing runtime overhead, was through raw pointers and unsafe code."_ If you're doing this then you're almost certainly invoking undefined behavior. The _only_ way to safely break Rust's aliasing rules is by using `UnsafeCell<T>` or any interior mutability type based on it. In your case, `RefCell` would probably work fine.

Comment: @ShadowRanger at first I opted to leave out anything relating to the widgets updates, but I've edited the code sample to include it now. Widgets need to be updated periodically so that they always hold recent system information, that is why they're mutable.

Comment: Could you not implement something like get_alignment_delay for all widgets? Allow all widgets to determine there own refresh interval, and then refresh based on the minimum value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust doesn't allow *uncontrolled*, shared, mutable access. For your application, you need shared, mutable access to the clock, so you have to pick a way to control it. There are many possibilities with different consequences.

1. You could put each widget in a `RefCell`, `Mutex` or `RwLock` to allow runtime-checked mutation.

   ```rust
   fn main() {
       let netstat = RefCell::new(NetworkStatus{});
       let clock = RefCell::new(Clock{});

       // note these are now `&` references, which may be shared
       let widgets: Vec<&RefCell<dyn Widget>> = vec![
           &netstat,
           &clock,
       ];

       loop {
           for w in widgets.iter() {
               w.borrow_mut().update_info();
           }

           for w in widgets.iter() {
               w.borrow().render();
           }

           std::thread::sleep(clock.borrow().get_alignment_delay());
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could make a note of where in the vector the clock is, then access it as `widgets[index_of_the_clock].get_alignment_delay()`. This might make sense if users can add and remove multiple animated widgets and you want to check with all of them how long to sleep.
3. You could require every widget to be interior-mutable (that is, to use things like `RefCell` for all mutable parts of itself) so that `update()` only needs `&self` instead of `&mut self`. Then you can share access to the widgets with `&` like in the code sample above, but without needing the wrapping `RefCell`. (This is probably less ergonomic than the first option.)

Note that in all of these cases, you may find that using a vector of references is limiting -- in particular, if you want to let the user add new widgets while the program is running, the vector should really *own* the widgets rather than borrowing them. This means the type of the vector would be `Vec<Box<dyn Widget>>` (or in case 1, `Vec<Box<RefCell<dyn Widget>>>`). This doesn't stop you from mutating the widgets because *ownership* includes the ability to mutate.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I guess I still haven't got the Rust mentality and should stop worrying too much about avoiding tiny runtime costs of borrow/reference tracking.
Your solution works perfectly, the only detail I'd like to add is that none of the variables need the "mut" qualifier.

Comment: @rockerbacon Fixed the `mut`s. One might indeed care about the costs of runtime borrow checking (or reference counting), but ten or even a hundred animated widgets aren't there yet.